# Should I use Ajax Timer?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax, timer, stopwatch

I want to have a stopwatch on the site, which displays running time on the label without reloading a page. Is it possible to do this on client side? Should I use Ajax timer or smth else from .net?

Website is in C#.

Some links or demos would be really helpful ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with basic JavaScript using [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp):

```
var totalSeconds = 0

function stopwatch() {
    // increment the seconds
    totalSeconds++;

    // display the seconds to the user
    document.getElementById("<%=myLabel.ClientID%>").innerHTML = "You have spent " + totalSeconds + " on this page.";

    // wait a second and call the timer again
    setTimeout("stopwatch()", 1000);
}

// trigger the timer
timer();
```

**Update**: If the user is going to be on the page for a while you probably want to display a slightly more user-friendly message then "You have spent 1000 seconds on this page". [Here's a quick JavaScript](http://snipplr.com/view/5327/elapsed-time-string-from-time-in-seconds/) function that'll transform the seconds into time elapsed.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do in javascript only. There are so many example out there. Just [google them](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=stopwatch+javascript&aq=f&aqi=g1g-m1&aql=&oq=). Here's [one](http://www.javascriptsearch.com/scripts/Clocks/stopwatch.html).